# Why is my test not animating correctly when dragged?

Tags: animation, drag

I am trying to create drag gesture of a text view that updates the text as it is dragged.  The drag is animated so that it has a smooth transition from point to point.  The problem is that the text lags the frame that contains it.

Here is my sample code to illustrate the problem:

struct DragTextDemo: View {

```
@State private var dragDistance: CGSize = .zero
@State private var lastDragDistance: CGSize = .zero

var body: some View {
    Text("Pos : \(dragDistance.width, specifier: "%.0f"), \(dragDistance.height, specifier: "%.0f")")
        .frame(width: 150, height: 60)
        .background(.red)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .offset(dragDistance)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ value in
                    withAnimation {
                        dragDistance = CGSize(
                            width: value.translation.width + lastDragDistance.width,
                            height: value.translation.height + lastDragDistance.height)
                    }
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                    lastDragDistance = dragDistance
                })
        )
}
```

}